# Very confusing [sefarim-books] [seforim-books] synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

[sefarim-books](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefarim-books) is a synonym of [jewish-books](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish-books); [seforim-books](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seforim-books) is a synonym of [books-generally](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books-generally).

This is extremely confusing.

If they both exist, they should both go to the same place. Which one should they map to?

Answer (score 7):

I think they should both map to [jewish-books](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish-books), because that's what sefarim/seforim are.

Comment: I tried to do synonymize 'seforim' to [tag:jewish-books] myself, but I was told that the tag needs to exist in the system before it can be a synonym. Maybe that's because it's already a synonym of something else?

Comment: Could be. If anyone (a mod?) manages to do it, please ping me.

Comment: @Scimonster according to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/jewish-books/synonyms [tag:seforim] is already a synonym of [tag:jewish-books].

Comment: @msh210 I'm pretty sure Shokhet meant "seforim-books", as that's what was asked about.

Comment: @Scimonster, oh. Well, in that case, I'll be glad to redirect the synonym to the correct tag per this answer once this question's been around for longer and this answer remains the community's choice. It's been less than a day so far.

Comment: @msh210 It's been a week, and my answer has three votes. Is that enough to decide to switch the synonyms?

Comment: IMO yes, but I cannot do it at the moment.

Comment: @msh210 All right; no rush. I would do it myself, but the system won't let me ( *see above comments* )

Comment: In accordance with the popularity of this answer and absence of another, I've removed the synonym _seforim-books_ of _books-generally_ and [suggested it](//judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) as a synonym of _jewish-books_.

Comment: @msh210 That suggestion has my upvote! Thanks :)

Comment: I would upvote as well, but lack the required score. :(